# EF Core EnsureDeleted throws "failed to login with user 'sa'"

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to implement unit / integration testing with EF Core by using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/sharing-databases) code from the Microsoft documentation.

But calling `EnsureDeleted()` doesn't work, it throws an error

> SqlException: Login failed for user 'sa'

This is the example from the MS docs:

```
public class SharedDatabaseFixture : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly object LockObject = new object(); 
    private static bool isDatabaseInitialized; 

    public SharedDatabaseFixture()
    {
        Connection = new SqlConnection("Server =; Database=; User Id=; Password=");

        Seed();
    
        Connection.Open();
    }

    public DbConnection Connection { get; }

    public OnlineMenuContext CreateContext(DbTransaction transaction = null)
    {
        var context = new OnlineMenuContext(
            new DbContextOptionsBuilder<OnlineMenuContext>().UseSqlServer(Connection)
                .Options
            );

        if (transaction != null)
        {
            context.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);
        }
    
        return context;
    }

    private void Seed()
    {
        lock (LockObject)
        {
            if (isDatabaseInitialized) return;

            using var context = CreateContext();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted(); // Crashes HERE                
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                    
            context.Products.Add(DummyData.Product);
            context.SaveChanges();

            isDatabaseInitialized = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() => Connection.Dispose();
}
```

I used the same connection string as in the application, it works 100%

`EnsureCreated()` works perfectly, if I remove `EnsureDeleted()` the tests are running as expected, except I should delete the database manually.

I tried to isolate the problem and created a console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection("Perfectly working connection string");
        
        var context = new Context(
            new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>().UseSqlServer(connection).Options);
        
        // context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        context.Database.EnsureDeleted(); // Crashes HERE
    }
}

class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options): base(options) { }
    private DbSet<Product> Products;
}

class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am using MacOs to run these examples

Maybe there is something I don't know about how `EnsureDeleted` works.

My question is: why does it throw this exception, and how to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I verified user SA's permissions using the code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-my-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15),
`SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions('dbo', 'SCHEMA')`

Here is the result:

[image: The permissions of user SA]

Comment: when you say "Perfectly working connection string" what type of connection type, has it got permission to delete the database? I think it due to some permissions,

Comment: I connect to SQL server db, with `"Server =localhost; Database=myDb; User Id=sa; Password=123456"` type of connection string, lack of permissions is a good theory, but I already checked it, **user `sa` has permissions to delete**

Comment: try creating database using your web app, then login to sql server management studio using sa account  and delete it manually that would rule out the permission issue,

Comment: I can delete databases manually using user `sa`, or you wanted to check something else?

Comment: 1) Be sure to include `Trusted_Connection=False;` and `Encrypt=False;` in your connection string.  2) Test the connection string in SSMS 3) Add `.EnableSensitiveDataLogging()` to UseSqlServer to ensure you see all runtime SQL generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry for the delay, Looks like when you sending **new SqlConnection("Perfectly working connection string")** causing this issue. try directly sending connection string as stated

```
 var context = new Context(
            new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>()
            .UseSqlServer(@"Server=xxx; Database=myDb; Encrypt=False;User Id=sa; Password=xxxxx").Options);
        
        var tr = context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        context.Database.Migrate();
        context.Database.EnsureDeleted(); // No Loner an issue it works
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

Comment: I am not an expert but what I understood is the way it manages connection is different when you pass dbconenction object https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution

I should've added `Persist Security Info=true` to my connection string

It was not so perfectly working after all :D

Comment: Yes just lost 2 hours of my life that I won't get back with this issue and found your comment :-) and adding Persist Security Info=true to the connection string does correct the issue.  thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else is still having trouble, ensure you are using

`using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;` and not `using System.Data.SqlClient;`

Comment: This saved me hours!

Comment: This resolved the issue for me too. Why in the world does System.Data.SqlClient not work but Microsoft.Data.SqlClient does???